# Simple JavaScript button click event will not fire

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events

My event handler will not fire.

```
    $("button").click(function() {
        console.debug("Yo");
    });
```

And I tried.

```
    const buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");

    for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {

        buttons[i].addEventListener("click", (event) => {
            console.debug("Yo");
        });
    }
```

But it doesn't fire. I have tried, `onclick`, `focus`, `onfocus` and various elements. I have tried in CodePen and it works.

I tried latest Chrome and latest Edge.

It's been 4 hours now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsers no longer default to showing verbose debug prints.

Notice it says "10 hidden" on the right there? That's diminutive and placed next to the cog so you think it has something to do with hidden configuration or something. They owe you £350 in lost time.

[image: Screenshot of browser tools console]